# For which Systems is my app compatible?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-10-mobile

I created an app with Visual Studio 2015 in this way : new Project -> Visual C# -> Windows -> Windows 8 -> Windows Phone.

My question is , is this app compatible with windows phone 7? I read something that the WinRT can make this happen, but I am not sure.

I tested the app on an Samsung device with Windows Phone 8.1 and it worked perfectly, can I assume that it works on Windows Phone 8 the same?

What about Windows 10 mobile? Is a Windows Phone 8.1 app installable on a device running on Windows 10 mobile?

I read the Wikipedia article about Windows Phone 8, but I did'nt get the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app will work on Windows Phone 8/8.1 and Windows 10 Mobile.

It will not work on Windows Phone 7 devices.

My advice is to check better how it works on Windows 10 mobile - you might have surprises where the UI is slighlty different or some controls won't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to decide which system runs the app in code that I can implement part twice?

Comment: It could be possible but I'd recommend to assess very well the entire application and investigate which parts might have issues on Windows 10 Mobile. Maybe everything will work very well. However, if you notice some things are not OK, I would create a separate application, just for Windows 10 Mobile (it can happen that things might get greatly simiplified on Windows 10 and you just have better support for your issue).